# ARM: Unexpected Link Register Content on Crashing Thread

Tags: ios, arm, stack-trace, cpu-registers, crash-dumps

I have an iOS Crash-dump [EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS] with register-state and stack-memory for crashed thread.

register Contents are:

```
r0 = 0x00000000    r1 = 0x288bf020    r2 = 0x01e7afe0    r3 = 0xd7741000
r4 = 0x01e7b000    r5 = 0x00000000    r6 = 0x1665a924    r11 = 0x00000000
r8 = 0x14e11af0    r9 = 0x00000000   r10 = 0x1df94d0c    r12 = 0x00000000
r7 = 0x1df94bb8    sp = 0x1df94bb8    lr = 0x00000000    pc = 0x3991a44a
```

LinkRegister(lr) and FramePointer(r7) seems to be inconsistent here.

If I ignore LinkRegister and trust FramePointer and use stack-memory to unwind call-stack with the help of FramePointer linkage, I get a reasonable back-trace(with ~15 frames).

If I trust LinkRegister which is 0 means there is no return address, I have no-where to go(no trace).

I don't understand why is LinkRegister 0? What could possibly be happening?
How can I reproduce this? or am I missing something.

Comment: Most likely something, somewhere, has corrupted a non-leaf stack frame - once execution gets back to that frame, reaches the end and pops the saved return address, boom. Pay special attention to anywhere the address of a local variable gets passed into a child function.

Comment: Could the value of lr have been pushed onto the stack? Or somewhere the lr register is being set to 0 when it should be a different register.

Comment: Isn't this related to being in Thumb mode.

Comment: `lr` maybe used as a general purpose register.  You need to checkout the code around `pc` (0x3991a44a).  You `fp` is matching the stack.  It maybe you are about to *return* and you have popped some bad return address (NULL)?  Really you need to show the code around `pc` in assembler and higher level source.  The compiler can use the registers in lots of different ways, depending on code gen options.